# GPG doesn't work in crontab

Tags: cron, gpg

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
PWD="supersecretpassword"
file="/backup/2do/example.txt"
echo before
echo $PWD | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -c $file
echo after
```

The scripts works perfectly fine if executed manually, but simply stops working when the gpg line is performed when performed as crontab.

GPG shows:

```
gpg: cannot open `/dev/tty': No such device or address
```

I'm grateful for any suggestions!

**Solution**:
add `--no-tty` to GPG

Comment: $PWD is very bad choice for a variable. it is a shell variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-vv` to the `gpg` command to see more output. It might have to do with a missing `~/.gnupg` though.

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me into the right direction: --no-tty

Comment: This is a good troubleshooting step as advice for everyone, but it seems that for a lot of people the real solution is `--no-tty` so this accepted answer could be improved if you turn the suggestion of a missing `~/.gnupg` into a list and add `--no-tty` as a second item on that list.

Answer (score 9):

```
/usr/bin/gpg --no-tty --passphrase-file /home/vouuuuuuuuu/settings/passfile.txt --decrypt-files /home/juhuuu/dirname/*.gpg;
```

- works fine now thank to `--no-tty`
- before in cron job log gpg: `cannot open`/dev/tty': No such device or address`
- so it could not execute before, now is fine!

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem just add the "--no-tty" option to your gpg command line.
answer was taken from a cached google [page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:By40sMnGF8AJ:www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/posts/2012/02/running_gpg_from_a_cron_or_application.html%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=no&client=ubuntu)

Comment: It also already was here as another answer.  http://serverfault.com/a/543201/205542